# Can't override Glassfish 4.1.0 Jersey version with 2.19 (in Java 8 app)

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, glassfish-4.1

We have a Java 6 application that needed to be upgraded to Java 8.
As part of that process, other components were also upgraded e.g. Glassfish, Jersey.
We can not get one part of our application to work now.

I did not perform the upgrade work but need to try to troubleshoot the problem as we have yet to find a consultant with the relevant knowledge to bring in to help us fix it.
I have next-to-no understanding of Glassfish and Jersey, so apologies in advance if I need to add to my question to clarify.

Our application is configured with Jersey 2.19 and Glassfish 4.1.0.
When we run the application on our test server and it fails, we get no error logging information.
In debug mode on a dev machine in a VM (Mac OS X El Capitan, IntelliJ 2016.1.2, Java 1.8.0_91) with Glassfish 4.1.0 installed locally, we get error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationAutoDiscoverable cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable

The developer who performed the upgrade thinks the issue is related to Glassfish using its own Jersey version rather than our specified 2.19.
In his local environment, he tried updating/replacing the Jersey within Glassfish as per
http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/
but that was unsuccessful.

We had a sun-web.xml file setup with delegate=false to override Glassfish’s Jersey

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
   <context-root>eden-node-app</context-root>
   <class-loader delegate="false" />
</sun-web-app>
```

We then realised for Glassfish 4.x we should be using glassfish-web.xml
https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.17/glassfish.html
(but recognising this is not for Glassfish 4.x)

so we switched to that

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>eden-node-app</context-root>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

and also did the additional step

”
In the GlassFish admin console, go to Configuration->JVM Settings, switch to the JVM Options tab and add the following option:

-Dcom.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.ws.rs,javax.ws.rs.core,javax.ws.rs.ext

Restart GlassFish for new JVM settings to take effect.
"

Still no success.

Are we correct in thinking it is a Jersey override issue? 
Can you please help with how to proceed?

Thanks in advance